# Using text validation on google forms to match number in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form that people will enter an ID into and I want to verify that that ID is in a column of a google sheet before they are allowed to submit the form, does anyone know how to do this?

I am struggling to find how to search the google sheet for that value with the functions available in the TextValidationBuilder in google apps script.

Comment: The  data won't get into the linked sheet until after they submit the form.

Comment: No, this ID will already be in the google sheet before they submit the form, I just want to check to make sure the ID entered is one of the ones in the sheet before they can submit the form.

Comment: There is no way to interact with the form while it is being fill out.

Comment: Hi, welcome. As Cooper says, you can NOT interact with the sheet while the form is being filled out. But you can use validation for the _form_ ID field, and you can upload values from a spreadsheet (but again... just to be clear:  while the form is being filled out, its not a dynamic interaction between the form & spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function setIdFromSheet() {
 const formURL = "*URL of your Form*";
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("targetSheet");
 let sheetValue = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
 let textValidation = 
 FormApp.createTextValidation().requireTextContainsPattern(sheetValue).build();
 const form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
 let formElement = form.getItemById(*ID of the emelemt from your form*);
 formElement.asTextItem().setValidation(textValidation);
}
```

You should replace:

1. "targetSheet" with the name of your sheet where you have the ID number you would like to use as text validation.
2. "A2" with the cell that contains the ID number to be used as text validation.

If you do not know how to get the item's ID of the form that will have the text validation, you can use this code:

```
function checkIDs(){
 const form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
 let items = form.getItems();
 for (var i in items) { 
   console.log(items[i].getTitle() + ': ' + items[i].getId());
 }
}
```

The item ID you obtain with the function above will not change unless you change the  item in the form.